# Map pandas column to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column containing index to be mapped.

df:

```
Date    Value   id
01-01-2011  99  -9999
01-02-2011  0   -9999
01-03-2011  5   4
01-01-2012  0   9
01-02-2012  1   0
01-03-2012  5   15
01-01-2013  11  -9999
01-02-2013  9   13
01-03-2013  1   22
```

This is how I am mapping:

```
df['value_from_array'] = numpy_array[df.id.unique()]
```

given some of the id are not in array example: -9999. This is throwing an index error. Any way to avoid index error and get 0 instead of index error.

Comment: You can replace the outlier index to 0 before doing this step? Anyway, please also post what is your `numpy_array`. Thank you

Comment: 0 is a valid index in this case row number 5. Sure, let me put numpy_array in the question. Ideally, need to return 0 if index not found. I tried something with try, except. But, that gave invalid syntax. will update further.

Answer (score 0):

Let's convert the array to `index -> array value` dictionary and map the dictionary to `id` column

```py
df['value_from_array'] = df['id'].map(dict(enumerate(numpy_array))).fillna(0)
```

If you insist on numpy array indexing, you can append `0` to the array and replace the `-9999` (or conditionally replace the value not in index range) to `-1` to index the previously added `0`

```py
df['value_from_array'] = np.concatenate((numpy_array, [0]))[df['id'].replace(-9999, -1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to avoid converting to dict if possible. So, I will try things on my own and also see other answer. But, this does solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a merge to me.

```py
numpy_array = np.random.rand(df.id.max() + 1)
df2 = df.merge(pd.Series(numpy_array, name='value_from_array'),
               left_on="id", 
               right_index=True, 
               how="left")

>>> df2
         Date  Value    id  value_from_array
0  01-01-2011     99 -9999               NaN
1  01-02-2011      0 -9999               NaN
2  01-03-2011      5     4          0.575414
3  01-01-2012      0     9          0.608703
4  01-02-2012      1     0          0.720560
5  01-03-2012      5    15          0.062212
6  01-01-2013     11 -9999               NaN
7  01-02-2013      9    13          0.310980
8  01-03-2013      1    22          0.195131
```